# Jquery function .change()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help.

I have this code in my jsp for capture event onchange with Jquery.

```
jQ("#idExp").change(function() { 
        onchangeExp();
    });

function onchangeExp(){
    alert("onchangeExp");
    if(jQ("#idExp").val()!="-1"){
        recuperarDatosAF();
    }else{
        jQ("#comboAF").attr('disabled',true);
        jQ("#comboAF").val("-1");
    }
}
```

I fill the combo whith this:

```
 jQ("#idExp").html("");
 jQ("#idExp").append("<option value='-1'>"+""+"</option>");
 jQ.each(expedientes, function(i,value){
     jQ("#idExp").append("<option value='"+i+"'>"+value.codExpediente+" </option>"); 
 });
```

Values of i is [0,1,2..]

The problem is that when I select the blank option from the combo with the value '-1', do not launch the onchange function runs, but instead when I select any other option from the combo, onchange function running.

You can not put negative values ​​of combo options?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: change event will not be called if you select an already selected option, I mean if that option with value='-1' is already selected and you select it then change event will not fire.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, this is working: http://jsfiddle.net/GRwct/

Comment: Thk lan , i fix with .prepend

Answer (score 1):

The default value for your select box is the value of your first option so the value of the select box does not change and the change event is not triggered.

Comment: Edit the post, filling the combo this way , i understand that the default value is -1 if it is the first option. I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try to add a real integer as value like this

```
jQ(function() {
    var j = jQ('#idExp');
    j.append(jQ('<option/>').attr('value', -1));
    j.change(function() {
        if(j.val() == -1) {
            jQ("#comboAF")
                .attr('disabled',true)
                .val("-1");
        }
        else {
            recuperarDatosAF();
        } 
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger change event when appending your option:

```
jQ("#idExp").append("<option value='-1'>"+""+"</option>").change();
```